# How to delete specific rows by comparing values against each other in multiple columns?

Tags: vba, excel

As you can see below, I want to delete the tests that has done repeatedly but has to retain one result by comparing the test ids and datedone. for example if you take test "AAA" it has been done three times so i want to eliminate two of thembased on test id and datedone. it has been done with 1,2,5 test ids respectively so i want to retain the latest one that is 5 and eliminate 1 and 2. but in some cases test ids are also same then i need to compare datedone. example "CCC" test has testid 2,2 respectively but datedone is 24.10.2011 and 31.12.2015 respectively. since i want always to retain the latest on i need to eliminate the 24.10.2015.  i tried a code(below example) but its not working properly the value of j, i is updated continuosly even after deleting a row which makes to sikp two rows every time it deletes something. Please help me i stuck at this for long time-

```
Tests    Datedone    Test Id      Result

AAA     13.10.2011      1         passed

BBB     13.10.2011      1         passed

CCC     24.10.2011      2         passed

AAA     15.10.2011      2         passed

DDD     31.12.2014      3         passed

CCC     31.12.2015      2         passed

GGG     15.10.2013      5         passed

HHH     25.10.2014      6         passed

AAA     31.12.2015      5         passed
```

Column 1,2,3 are TEST,Datedone & Testid respectively in code

```
Sub formattest1consolidate()
 'not working
 Dim i, j, rangevale,  As Long
 Dim cell, rng,  As range
 Sheets("").Activate
 rangevale = range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
For Each cell In range("A2:A" & rangevale)
 For i = 1 To rangevale
  For j = i + 1 To rangevale
  If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) And Cells(i, 3) = Cells(j, 3) And Cells(i, 2) = Cells(j, 2) Then
  'do nothing
  ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) And Cells(i, 3) > Cells(j, 3) Then rng.Item(j).EntireRow.Delete
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) And Cells(i, 3) < Cells(j, 3) Then rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) And Cells(i, 3) = Cells(j, 3) And Cells(i, 2) > Cells(j, 2) Then rng.Item(j).EntireRow.Delete
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) And Cells(i, 3) = Cells(j, 3) And Cells(i, 2) < Cells(j, 2) Then rng.Item(i).EntireRow.Delete
 End If
    Next j
    Next i
    Next cell

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Public Sub DeleteRepeats()
Const FORMULA_REPEATS As String = _
"=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$<lastrow>,A2,$C$2:$C$<lastrow>,C2)=1," & _
    "MAX(IF($A$2:$A$<lastrow>=A2,$C$2:$C$<lastrow>))=C2," & _
    "MAX(IF(($A$2:$A$<lastrow>=A2)*($C$2:$C$<lastrow>=C2),$B$2:$B$<lastrow>))=B2)"
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastrow As Long


    With ActiveSheet

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Columns("E").Insert
        .Range("E1").Value = "tmp"
        .Range("E2").FormulaArray = Replace(FORMULA_REPEATS, "<lastrow>", lastrow)
        .Range("E2").AutoFill .Range("E2").Resize(lastrow - 1)
        Set rng = .Range("A2").Resize(lastrow - 1)
        .Range("A1:E1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="FALSE"
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete

        .Columns("E").Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: hey bob, Thank u very much for ur effort. its working perfect. can u suggest me any place or book to see to learn new techniques which i can use. i am very new in VBA :)

Comment: The problem is that learning VBA is very simple, it is a simple language with few structures to learn. But the language is pointless on its own, it is the application object model that you need to understand and program with, and this is only obtained by practice and experience.I find the best place to learn all of this is by joining forums and looking at questions and answers there, and of course by playing and practicing with the application.